# Covering/Matching Problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, matching-theory

My problem is as follows:

> Let $G$ be a graph. Suppose that $C$ is a vertex covering of $G$ and that $M$ is a matching of $G$. Prove that $|M| \le |C|$. What is the implication of this inequality for a vertex covering $C'$ and a matching $M'$ of $G$ such that $|C'|=|M'|$?

I can obviously show this for specific graphs G, but I'm struggling to form a general proof. Can you please help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: show that a vertex can "see" at most one edge of a matching.

Comment: Hint for the second part. If you have such a $C^\prime$ and $M^\prime$, can you have a *larger* matching than $M^\prime$? Can you have a *smaller* vertex cover than $C^\prime$?